# Shell script not working after scheduling it in crontab

Tags: shell, cron

Hi The below script is working fine when executing from the command prompt but it is not giving any result when scheduled in cron. Please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
db_mode()
{
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s  << eof
system/xxxxx@<DB_NAME>
SET LINES 132
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
select open_mode from v\$database;
exit;
eof
}
state=`db_mode`
echo $state > /home/oracle/dba/scripts/monitor/state.log
```

Hi all,

I scheduled the job with -l and it seems to have worked. 
This is how I have scheduled the job now

*/1 * * * * /bin/bash -l /home/oracle/dba/scripts/monitor/db_mode.sh

Earlier I scheduled it as

*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /home/oracle/dba/scripts/monitor/db_mode.sh

Thanks all.

Comment: what is your cronjob expression?

Comment: Hi all, I scheduled the job with -l and it seems to have worked. This is how I have scheduled the job now */1 * * * * /bin/bash -l /home/oracle/dba/scripts/monitor/db_mode.sh

Comment: nice! Please [edit] your question with these important details

Comment: Where is ORACLE_HOME set? Should the final line be ">" or ">>"? And you may also try changing the shebang to /bin/sh

Answer (score 1):

mostly this variable is not seen by the script when running from cron

> $ORACLE_HOME

use the full path and it should work

in general dont depend on any environment variable when running from cron so if sqlplus  depend on environment variables you have to set them in the script so that they are seen

the reason for this is that cron is not running from normal shell and it does not have the initialization you get when loggin in to normal shell in .bashrc etc

Answer (score 0):

Try sourcing your .bashrc or .profile first:

```
*/1 * * * * source /home/oracle/.bashrc; /home/oracle/dba/scripts/monitor/db_mode.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Cron will not dump output here and there, as it doesn't run with a "standard input" or "standard output," since it has no "controlling terminal" associated with it.  Only I/O to and from specified files will work.  Never mind that $ORACLE_JAZZ.